# java.lang.VerifyError in stand-alone thin client websphere 7 application

Tags: websphere-7, corba, thin-client

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties);
Object service = context.lookup(jndiName);
```

last line throw exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/ibm/rmi/corba/ORB, method: objectToIOR signature: (Lorg/omg/CORBA/Object;)Lcom/ibm/CORBA/iiop/IOR;) Incompatible object argument for function call
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:322)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:363)
    at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:59)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:357)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:799)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
```

How to solve this problem?

classpath contient

- com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
- com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar